# Kaleo workflow, error with groovy code

Tags: groovy, content-management-system, liferay

Almost time it work fine, but sometime it throw an exception(see stacktrace), can anyone show me why please !
I have some groovy code for my workflow definition, This code to connect to database and determine next step of webcontent base on Categorization properties. This is Liferay 6.1 ga 1, kaleo workflow definition code(Condition node):

```
<script> <![CDATA[
        import groovy.sql.Sql;
        import java.util.List;
        import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
        import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;
        import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowHandler;
        import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil;
        import com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetCategory;
        import com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetEntry;
        import com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetRenderer;
        import com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetRendererFactory;
        import com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil;
        import com.liferay.portal.model.WorkflowInstanceLink;
        import com.liferay.portal.service.WorkflowInstanceLinkLocalServiceUtil;

        try{
            String className = (String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_NAME);
            WorkflowHandler workflowHandler = WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.getWorkflowHandler(className);
            AssetRendererFactory assetRendererFactory = workflowHandler.getAssetRendererFactory();

            long classPK = GetterUtil.getLong((String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
            long companyId = GetterUtil.getLong((String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID));
            long groupId = GetterUtil.getLong((String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_GROUP_ID)); 
            AssetRenderer assetRenderer = workflowHandler.getAssetRenderer(classPK);
            AssetEntry assetEntry = assetRendererFactory.getAssetEntry(assetRendererFactory.getClassName(), assetRenderer.getClassPK());
            List<AssetCategory> assetCategories = assetEntry.getCategories();

            WorkflowInstanceLink workflowInstanceLink = WorkflowInstanceLinkLocalServiceUtil.getWorkflowInstanceLink(companyId, groupId, className, classPK);
            long instanceId = workflowInstanceLink.getWorkflowInstanceId(); 

            sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CGATE1.1_TNMT_KG', 'postgres', '1234567', 'org.postgresql.Driver');
            long cateId;
            String[] nextTransitionName;
            HashMap<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for (AssetCategory assetCategory : assetCategories) {
                cateId = assetCategory.getCategoryId();
                row = sql.firstRow("SELECT cchc_fun_cmsworkflow_nexttask(?,?) as nexttask", [cateId, instanceId]);
                if(row.nexttask != null){                       
                    String nextTaskStr = row.nexttask;  

                    if(nextTaskStr.equalsIgnoreCase("Done")){
                        returnValue = "Duyệt"; return;
                    }

                    context.put("roleprefix", nextTaskStr);
                    serviceContext.setAttribute("context", context);
                    nextTransitionName = nextTaskStr.split('_');
                    if(nextTransitionName[0].equalsIgnoreCase("BT")){
                        returnValue = "Biên tập"; return;
                    }else if(nextTransitionName[0].equalsIgnoreCase("LD")){ 
                        returnValue = "Lãnh đạo"; return;
                    }else if(nextTransitionName[0].equalsIgnoreCase("XB")){
                        returnValue = "Xuất bản";
                        System.out.println("Xuất bản");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
                returnValue ="Duyệt"; return;
        }
        returnValue = "Hủy";
        ]]> </script>
    <script-language>groovy</script-language>
```

stacktrace:

```
    07:58:39,150 ERROR [ParallelDestination:109] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/kaleo_graph_walker, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.graph.PathElement@161a2f1, values={principalPassword=null, principalName=11322, companyId=1}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:31)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:106)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:669)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:580)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy293.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.scripting.ScriptingUtil.eval(ScriptingUtil.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.condition.ScriptingConditionEvaluator.evaluate(ScriptingConditionEvaluator.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.condition.MultiLanguageConditionEvaluator.evaluate(MultiLanguageConditionEvaluator.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.node.ConditionNodeExecutor.doExecute(ConditionNodeExecutor.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.node.BaseNodeExecutor.execute(BaseNodeExecutor.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.graph.DefaultGraphWalker.follow(DefaultGraphWalker.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:320)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.aop.DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.invoke(DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy462.follow(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.runtime.graph.messaging.PathElementMessageListener.doReceive(PathElementMessageListener.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:25)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ArrayUtil, method: createArray signature: ()[Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal type in constant pool
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyRequest.execute(ProxyRequest.java:66)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyMessageListener.receive(ProxyMessageListener.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.SynchronousDestination.send(SynchronousDestination.java:39)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.sender.DirectSynchronousMessageSender.send(DirectSynchronousMessageSender.java:60)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.sender.DefaultSingleDestinationSynchronousMessageSender.send(DefaultSingleDestinationSynchronousMessageSender.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.messaging.proxy.MessagingProxyAdvice.doInvokeSynchronous(MessagingProxyAdvice.java:106)
    at com.liferay.portal.messaging.proxy.MessagingProxyAdvice.invoke(MessagingProxyAdvice.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1870.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ArrayUtil, method: createArray signature: ()[Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal type in constant pool
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.builder.AstBuilderTransformation.visit(AstBuilderTransformation.groovy:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:302)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:814)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:511)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:739)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:766)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:757)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.groovy.GroovyExecutor.getCompiledScript(GroovyExecutor.java:90)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.groovy.GroovyExecutor.eval(GroovyExecutor.java:51)
    at com.liferay.portal.scripting.ScriptingImpl.eval(ScriptingImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodHandler.invoke(MethodHandler.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.proxy.ProxyRequest.execute(ProxyRequest.java:57)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: my host server sometime auto restart, so i put my tomcat server on service mode, but when i do this, my code begin to unstable working